# Javascript function call with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a problem with this code, when I click the button it should do the function "hello" and open an alert but it doesn't work.

```js
function hello(){
  alert("hi");
  }

document.getElementById("one").onclick = hello();
```

```html
<button id="one">Click me </button>
```

I know that I could simply do like this

```
button onclick="hello()";
```

but I need it to work with the javascript version. Basically my question is: Is there a way to open the function "hello" when I click the button without putting the onclick in the button tag??

Comment: Don't call the function, just assign the reference: `= hello;`

Comment: don't assign onclick, use .addEventListener('click', hello); instead. I will not create an answer to explain why but you can find out easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem, but I couldn't find a canonical answer to link you to.

Your issue this line:

```
document.getElementById("one").onclick = hello()
```

which *executes* the function `hello` then assigns the return value of that function to `onclick`.

You really want this:

```
document.getElementById("one").onclick = hello;
```

which assigns a function reference to the onclick property.

That said, the use of `onclick` is rather out-dated and use of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is recommended for a number of reasons.

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3007402/542251) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a function to the `onclick` property.

You are *immediately* calling the `hello` function and assigning its return value (which is `undefined`).

Don't put `()` after the function name.

```
document.getElementById("one").onclick = hello;
```